# With Assets 2 is it possible to restrict upload access to a folder within an S3 bucket?

Tags: assets

Currently I have about 20 upload paths set in the native EE file manager. all of them point to a variation of subfolders within my main /images folder.

I was originally planning to use Assets 2 to host all of my images in a single Amazon S3 bucket like images.domain.com and use the same structure I currently have to restrict access to specific sub folders.

After playing around with Assets 2, it doesn't apear that you can restrict to a subfolder as restrictions are set on a per bucket basis.

Is there a way to do what I'm wanting?

Comment: I was hoping to use Assets 2 in the same manner. I don't know the answer here but wanted to watch this thread as I'll likely run into this should I choose to go with S3 integration as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it’s all or nothing – the most you can do to restrict access is prevent certain member groups from accessing the Assets MCP in its entirety, and limiting individual Assets fields to specific EE upload directories and S3 buckets.

Fine-grained permissions are on Assets’ v.Next list, so they’ll be coming soon. (Probably 2.2.)

Comment: Thanks Brandon. I'm thankful we at least have S3 integration, and I'm expectantly waiting for 2.2!

Comment: Was this ever addressed in future Assets releases?