# Is it possible to convert an EE File Upload path to Assets S3?

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, s3

I currently have 31 native EE file upload paths all pointing to a location within /images.

I'd like to serve all of my image assets from an S3 bucket, so I've created images.domainname.com. I've also copied the entire image structure to this bucket.

Is it possible to run a query on the existing upload paths and convert them to point to the S3 source instead of the native one?

Other than losing the ability to [restrict upload directories](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/4937/with-assets-2-is-it-possible-to-restrict-upload-access-to-a-folder-within-an-s3), is there a reason to not do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see Andris' answer here:

[Migrating Assets to S3](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/7239/migrating-assets-to-s3)

> Backup your database first, of course, but theoretically this should be easy-peasy: Just add your S3 sources in the settings and then, in the Assets File Manager just drag all your files and folders from your EE sources to S3 sources and that's that - no changes in entries should be required at all.

Comment: Thanks Lisa, I'll try this.  If it's as simple as it sounds I'm going to be extremely impressed!

Comment: Lisa, when dragging files/folders to an S3 source, does it attempt to copy all of these files? I'm asking because I've already mirrored the entire folder structure.

Comment: It's a move, not a copy...but do you mean if you drag an entire folder, will it move the structure as is?

Comment: Since I've already manually duplicated the files and folder structure to s3 (via ftp), there's no need for me to move files again.  I'm wondering if it's possible to just simply switch an ee upload directory to an s3 type since the files live in the exact same place on s3.  Does that make sense?

Comment: It ... kind of makes sense?  It is not possible to simply switch an upload directory from local to S3.  It's not the same thing as say, a custom field that you can just swap between different fieldtypes: this structure is in different parts of the code (one first-party, one third-party), etc.  Have you set up your S3 instance and indexed in Assets? You may need to use some queries to do any bulk updates past that.